# Sql Server Count of Tables

Tags: sql

I need to get a count of all table's row count in sql along with min date (earliest record) and max (latest record). Can someone help me how can it be done in single query?

challenge is to get min and max date as idea is to have info about table that it have the date range from where to where so we can do the necessary operation.

```
Output:-
DBName Table_name Count Min Max

min-table first record comes in 2012-01-03
max-table last record comes in 2013-01-03
```

Comment: have you tried min and max aggregation methods? or what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'BASE%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'sys%'
```

This query returns all tables . You can use dynamic querying to get each table and count rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get date of first and last record if you have Date field in all table.

You can use this query

```
Exec sp_MSforeachtable ' Select Count(*),Min(DateField),Max(DateField) From ? '
```

And for record of all table use this query :

```
Select
    S.name + '.' + T.name As TableName ,
    SUM( P.rows ) As RowCont 

From sys.tables As T
    Inner Join sys.partitions As P On ( P.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID )
    Inner Join sys.schemas As S On ( T.schema_id = S.schema_id )
Where
    ( T.is_ms_shipped = 0 )
    AND 
    ( P.index_id IN (1,0) )
    And
    ( T.type = 'U' )

Group By S.name , T.name
```